VSCode local cache of file from SSH
does VSCode store a local cache of the files I was working with via SSH?
I've been coding in VSCode using SSH, but the server crashed and I'm trying to recover my uncommitted codes.
The system I'm using is Windows and the server is Ubuntu.
